# What cannot be migrated from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2007, migration

We are planning to migrate a SharePoint 2007 site to SharePoint 2013.

I want to know, Is it possible to migrate everything from SP 2007 site means What can be migrated and what cannot be migrated.

Please let me know in detail.

Answer (score 5):

**First,** you should be aware of the SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) is not supported edition for upgrading to SharePoint 2013! So you must

- Migrate from SP 2007 to SP 2010.
- Then Migrate from SP 2010 to SP 2013.

For more details check, [Review supported editions and products for upgrading to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/b1088a52-179f-4120-8fb5-0ed3e6c088b1(v=office.16).aspx)

---

**Second,** to know **What can be migrated and what cannot be migrated**. you should first run `Preupgradecheck` in MOSS 2007 server to get the actual answer

```
stsadm.exe -o preupgradecheck
```

This will provide information for your SharePoint 2007 farm and actions that may be required to be taken prior to upgrading to SharePoint 2010.

> **Note:** It is better to have October CU: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976730/

Check the detail steps at [Migrate from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 - Step by Step](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/migrate-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010.html#ixzz4v6WTwSOv)

---

Once you complete the migration from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010,

- You should make sure that everything is working fine,
- Then start the migration from SP 2010 to SP 2013 as mentioned in the official MSDN article [Upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493272(v=office.16).aspx)

**By the way**, if you don't like to read and apply you can watch [MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2013 Migration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbBI0-_6hBc) and apply!

---

**Finally,** If you don't need to face this big headache, you can use a 3rd party Migration tool like:

- Sharegate - [Migrating from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013](https://get.share-gate.com/migration-sharepoint-2007-2013?gclid=CjwKCAjw3_HOBRBaEiwAvLBbohFsQZ6br5YHdP5ia7QDI_K6lqczv0VcLeF3_nLXoTK1qd4kEd4bwRoC4RMQAvD_BwE)
- [Metalogix](https://www.metalogix.com/blog/move-sharepoint-2010-to-2016)